# C Programming, why can't I use strcpy() with indexes?

Tags: c

Here is an example:

```
int main()
{
    char string1[8];
    char string2[7];
    strcpy(string1, "Heloooo");
    strcpy(string2, "Helloo");
    printf("%d", strcmp(string1[2], string2[5]));
    return(0);
}
```

Won't return anything, even though it should return >0, 0, or <0. If I remove the indexes though like:

```
    printf("%d", strcmp(string1, string2));
```

It'll work fine. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `string1[2]` returns a single character. `strcmp` does not take characters as arguments.

Comment: `string1[2]` and `string2[5]` are `char`s, `strcmp` compares strings.

Comment: Or use `strcmp(string1 + 2, string2 + 5);` What is your intent though?

Comment: As mentioned the [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function expects to pointers to `char` as arguments. The type of e.g. `string1[2]` is of type `char`, not the expected `char *`. Any good compiler should tell you this (always read your error ***and warning*** messages). I suggest you [get a couple of good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read more.

Comment: If you *really*  want to compare single characters, you *can* do `string1[2] == string2[5]`.

Comment: If your compiler didn't complain about the abuse of `strcmp()`, you are misusing your compiler.  Either turn on the warnings, or get a better compiler.  You (like everyone else, me included — me especially) need all the help you can get from the compiler.  Don't scorn its advice (and any warning it generates is salient advice); it knows a lot more about C than you do.

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` takes a pair of character pointers, while `string1[x]` is not a pointer, but a character:

```
printf("%d", strcmp(&string1[2], &string2[5]));
```

or

```
printf("%d", strcmp(string1+2, string2+5));
```

Note that although `string1` and `string2` are arrays, C compiler converts them to character pointers without additional operators.

Answer (score 0):

The function `strcmp` expects pointers as the arguments. See the prototype: `int strcmp(const char * s1, const char * s2)`;

`string1[2]` and `string2[5]` are just characters `'l'` and `'o'`.

```
printf("%d", strcmp(string1[2], string2[5])); // will not compile 

printf("%d", strcmp(&string1[2], &string2[5])); // will return -3 with my compiler GCC 5.3.0
```

`&string1[2]` is a pointer to `string1[2]` character

`&string2[5]` is a pointer to `string2[5]` character

Note:

> The strcmp() and strncmp() functions return an integer less than,
>   equal to, or greater than zero if s1 (or the first n bytes thereof) is
>   found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.

However, the exact return value depends on the implementation.

For this implementation:

```
int strcmp_fast (const char * s1, const char * s2)
{
    for(; *s1 == *s2; ++s1, ++s2)
        if(*s1 == 0)
            return 0;
    return *(const unsigned char *)s1 - *(const unsigned char *)s2;
}
```

the:

```
printf("%d", strcmp_fast(&string1[2], &string2[5]));
```

printed value is `-3`.

Answer (score 0):

str[ndx] evaluates to a char but the function expects a char *,[] produces an l-value so you can take its address &str[ndx] and get what you are after.